# Why Two different screen size & resolution, use a common layout?

Tags: android, screen-size

I have Xiaomi Mi Max (6.4") with 1920 x 1080 resolution and a Sony Xperia S (4.3") with 1280 x 720 resolution.

I set out my layouts like this:

[image]

No matter what I did, every time both of the phones use the same layout. For example both of them use layout-normal or use layout-sw320 (if I add the folder).

This causes problems as the layouts for this two phones must be different. In this situation one phone displays the UI correctly while the other one shows a compressed one.

I want each phone pick the right layout, but they don't.

What is wrong?

Comment: are you using some pictures/drawables in your layout?

Comment: Yes, I use some ImageButtons and a GridView with drawables.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

because they have same characterists (for the the system). dpi or dimension

Comment: Any solution then?

Comment: there are a lot of solution. some more elegant. i will grab the screen resolution and load 2 different layout let say R.layout.layout_xiami or R.layout.sony. i know it sucks but is a way. or you can check if you can find some characteristics that can let you identify which phone you are running on (manufacter for example, which is even worst ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue in my project. You'll have to open each layout.xml of each folder and rewrite the dimensions for different devices. You can use live preview/preview window in AS to change the device (Mobile, Tablets 7' & 10' etc, TV or wearable) and then set your views in xml. IF you are using Drawables in your layouts you should use Batch Drawable Import plugin, this plugin will take one image and make its different sizes for all layouts.

Comment: even after you've set the dimensions properly for all layouts/devices, if your drawables aren't properly resized you'll get distorted images. Drawable Import Batch is the best solution to drawables issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, for system, they have the same characterists.
Look at this for more informations : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

When I develop for multiple screen resolution/dimension, I set strings too like this :

I put this on strings-hdpi :

```
<string name="screen_size">HDPI</string>
```

I do the same for mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi...
Then, I put a small textView in my layout only for debugging with

```
<TextView
   android:text="@string/screen_size"/>
```

That way, I see easily where is the problem.

Comment: I did the same exact thing, I received the same result on both text views(both of them displays xhdpi for example).

Comment: So, I think you need to do your best to make layout "compatible" with this two screen. IMO, mdpi,hdpi, ... is the best for supporting multiple screen. Maybe, try to build your layout a little bit different, it may help. Or try the same thing mdpi, hdpi,... but with screen resolution : right-click on dimens folder -> new -> and select the properties you want. Maybe post your layout, we may help you.